# iPhone - How to customize the UINavigationBar back button with my texture background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, back-button

I am able to customize the back button on my navigation bar, but in order for me to show the left arrow shape, do I need to create my customized image with the left arrow specifically?

Or there is a way to use the original back button with the arrow shape, while just apply my background image onto it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10586915/1378447

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set **yourButton** the customized image with the left arrow

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =  [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:yourButton] autorelease];
```

You cannot modify the original BACK button.

Comment: that mean the image used for the custom view of my button should have have the left arrow by itself?

Comment: so, I need to draw the left arrow shape onto my customized image specifically... Thanks.